# Crear usuario desde un usuario creado laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy desarrollando un sistema para la uni que comprende un panel de administracion con roles y permisos asignados, para poder entrar al sistema debes estar logueado trabajando con el ***middleware*** prederterminado ***auth***, y en base a los permisos que tenga según su rol podra acceder a los modulos del sistema, la idea es que solo un usuario con permisos pueda generar otro usuario, estoy tratando de usar el mismo register mediante el register ***controller*** de ***auth*** pero al parecer me esta generando conflicto el hecho de que ya hay un usuario logeado.

Anexo código de rutas:

```
//rutas para el panel de adminsitracion 


Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('admin/home',function(){
        return view('admin.home');
         })->name('admin');   

//----------------------------------Usuarios------------------------------------  
    Route::post('admin/users/store','UserController@store')->name('users.store')
    ->middleware('can:users.create');

    Route::get('admin/users','UserController@index')->name('users.index')
    ->middleware('can:users.index');

    Route::get('admin/users/create','UserController@create')->name('users.create')
    ->middleware('can:users.create');

    Route::put('admin/users/{user}','UserController@update')->name('users.update')
    ->middleware('can:users.edit');

    Route::get('admin/users/show/{user}','UserController@show')->name('users.show')
    ->middleware('can:users.show');

    Route::delete('admin/users/{user}','UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy')
    ->middleware('can:users.destroy');

    Route::get('admin/users/{user}','UserController@edit')->name('users.edit')
    ->middleware('can:users.edit');



 });

 // fin de rutas para el panel de administracion


 // Rutas para autenticacion de usuario
Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Vista del ***index*** de usuarios que manda a crear:

```
<div class="container space_top">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Cotizaciones
                    @can('users.create')
                        <a href="{{route ('users.create')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
                    @endcan
            </div>  
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead class="table table-primary">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th >Descripcion</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Detalle</th>
                            <th>Actualizar</th>
                            <th>Eliminar</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td>
```

Vista de la creacion de usuarios:

```
   @extends('admin.template')

    @section('content')
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Register') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: Por experiencia, es mucho mas sencillo hacer un CRUD de usuarios nuevo y deshabilitar la posibilidad de registrarse. Veo que ya tienes las rutas y el controlador,  solo cambiando la ruta en el attributo action del form para que apunte a ('admin/users/store','UserController@store')->name('users.store) y agregando la lógica en el método store para guardar los datos en DB, te ahorrará mucho tiempo y quedará mas limpio

Answer (score 1):

Tienes problemas por lo que dices, tienes un usuario logueado. Si utilizas el mismo cuestionario con la misma ruta. La lógica de ***laravel*** dice que este usuario cuando se registra automáticamente inicia sesión en el servidor.

Puedes agregar un nuevo método a la clase:

> **App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;**

```
    routes/web.php
    Route::post('registr2', 'Auth\RegisterController@registroNuevo');


    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use React\HttpClient\Request;

    class RegisterController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Register Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
        | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
        | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
        |
        */

        use RegistersUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after registration.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
        /**
         * Este es el nuevo metodo para registrar usuarios.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * 
         */

        public function registroNuevo(Request $request)
        {
            $data = $request->all();
            $this->validator($data);
            $this->create($data);
        }



        /**
         * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
         */
        protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \App\User
         */
        protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Obviamente cuando registres al usuario tendrás que mandar a llamar al método ***registroNuevo***. Este método como tal no iniciara la sesión automática.

Lo que hace este método que te propongo simplemente valida los datos del usuario y lo crea. Se vale de los métodos ya definidos del mismo controlador.

Comment: Una pregunta al crear el metodo nuevo me dice Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::registroNuevo does not exist.

Comment: En el codigo que pusistes hay 2 funciones de crear hay algun motivo para ello o no por que de entrada el editor me marca como un error, si elimino una de ellas me muestra ese error: BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::registroNuevo does not exist.

Comment: perdón solo debe de haber una. Tienes que hacer una ruta que llame al controlador en el método especifico.