# Cómo poder usar RegisterController cuando uno está logueado laravel?

Tags: laravel

quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar, necesito usar el registercontroller que trae laravel para poder registar a un nuevo usuario, pero esta acción solo la puede hacer alguien que ya está dentro del sistema, les comparto mi registercontroller ya modificado.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Model_has_Roles;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'id_empresa' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            'id_rol' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
            'telefono' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999999', 'min:00000000'],
            'direccion' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'sueldo' => ['numeric','min:0.01','max:0.99'],
            //'foto' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
          ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
          $request = request();
          $file = $request->file('foto');
          $nom_imagen = time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $upload_path = 'imagenes/';
          $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $nom_imagen;
          $success = $file->move($upload_path, $nom_imagen);

        } else  {
            $nom_imagen = '';
        }
        $user = User::create([
            'id_empresa' => $request->input('id_empresa'),
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'nombre' => $request->input('nombre'),
            'telefono' => $request->input('telefono'),
            'direccion' => $request->input('direccion'),
            'sueldo' => $request->input('sueldo'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'foto' => $nom_imagen,
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);

        //Auth::guard()->login($user);

        $rol = new Model_has_Roles;
        $rol->role_id = $request->id_rol;
        $rol->model_type ='App/User';
        $rol->model_id = Auth::id();

        //return redirect('/home');
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        // return Validator::make($data, [
        //     'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        //     'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        //     'telefono' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999999', 'min:00000000'],
        //     'direccion' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        //     'sueldo' => ['numeric','min:0.01','max:0.99'],
        //     //'foto' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        //     'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        //     'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
        // ]);
    }


    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        // $request = request();
        // $file = $request->file('foto');
        // $nom_imagen = time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // $upload_path = 'imagenes/';
        // $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $nom_imagen;
        // $success = $file->move($upload_path, $nom_imagen);

        // return User::create([
        //     'name' => $data['name'],
        //     'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        //     'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
        //     'direccion' => $data['direccion'],
        //     'sueldo' => $data['sueldo'],
        //     'email' => $data['email'],
        //     'foto' => $nom_imagen,
        //     'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        // ]);

    }
}
```

Leí esto pero no se aplica a lo que quiero:
[Crear usuario desde un usuario creado laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286212/crear-usuario-desde-un-usuario-creado-laravel)

PD: estoy usando laravel 8.
PD2: no quiero que me loguee con el nuevo usuario que estoy creando.
PD3: estoy usando la vista del registercontroller, pero le estoy mandando datos de otro controlador.

Gracias.

Comment: creo que forzosamente debes de usar middlewares, revisa la documentación para que entiendas cómo funcionan https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Comment: No me podrias dar un ejemplo de como podria hacer para lo que quiero? en mi routes->web tengo esto: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {